# Однородные члены предложения

Tags: синтаксис

Скажите, в данном предложении один ряд однород. членов или два?

"Там будет  лишь омытый дождем мокрый луг под огромным небом, несколько деревьев вдали, да бегущие по влажной траве тени сизых туч, гонимых ветром".

Луг, несколько деревьев, тени туч - это однород. подлежащие. А вот обстоятельства: под небом, вдали - относятся к сказуемому будет. Они являются однородными? Если я прав, то как составить схему?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Там будет лишь луг, несколько деревьев да тени. Это однородные подлежащие, отнесенные к одному сказуемому и обстоятельству "там".

Всё остальное - определения, отнесенные к подлежащим, в том числе несогласованные обстоятельственные определения "под огромным небом", "вдали".

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Vera,помогите пожалуйста ещё с одним предложением!

Answer (score -1):

"Там будет лишь омытый дождем мокрый луг под огромным небом, несколько деревьев вдали, да бегущие по влажной траве тени сизых туч, гонимых ветром". ------

подл. - там (за деревней)----
сказ. - будет (есть, находится)----
доп. - луг, деревьев, тени----

Можно принять дополнения как подлеж. и Там как обст., это не будет ошибкой синтаксич. разбора, но будет стилистическим инвалидом.
Лишь омытый дождем мокрый луг под огромным небом, несколько деревьев вдали, да бегущие по влажной траве тени сизых туч, гонимых ветром, будет там.

Comment: >> это не будет ошибкой синтаксич. разбора

Это как раз *будет* ошибкой, и очень грубой. За это двойки ставят. А вы хотя бы добавляли "по моему мнению", "мне кажется" или что-либо подобное.